# Why are instantiated modules often given the net name "u"?

Tags: verilog, naming-conventions, terminology, hdl

In industry and in many tutorials such as [this one](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/hierarchy3.html) (`counter U(clk,enable,reset,data);`) and [this one](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/syntax3.html) (`adder_hier U (result,carry,r1,r2,ci);`), modules are often called `u` or given the prefix/suffix `u_`. I've always accepted this but I'm not sure what it stands for.

What's this `u` mean? I can't find any info online and it's a tricky thing to google.

**Edit:** I realize that this isn't an explicit programming question, but SO has tags for terminology and naming conventions so I think it's appropriate to ask. This has been flagged for "opinion based" which I certainly don't think it is.

Comment: The meaning behind **U** is certainly not opinion based, but the choice to use it may be. :smile:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from an IEEE/ASME standard for naming components (*reference designators*) on a printed circuit board: R-resistor, C-capacitor, U-Integrated Circuit. I'm assuming like in many other standards, **I** and **O** are not used because they are too easily confused with **1** and **0**.

As schematics gradually evolved from PCBs to ICs, this naming convention stuck.

See https://www.asme.org/products/codes-standards/reference-designations-for-electrical-and-electron and https://standards.ieee.org/standard/315-1975.html

Comment: Thanks! This answer explains why it's `U` and your info helped dig deeper about what `U` stands for. `U` represents any of "inseparable assembly, integrated-circuit package, microcircuit, micromodule, photon-coupled isolator" in the spec. It seems to contended whether or not the `U` stands for "unrepairable" or "unspecified". However, this [Altium blog](https://resources.altium.com/pcb-design-blog/getting-started-in-altium-designer-the-schematic) takes the stance it stands for "unrepairable" so that's what I'm inclined to believe.